# Apply acoustic indices to each component of a list of wave objects in R

Tags: r, wav, acoustics

I am looking to apply a function which computes four acoustic indices (H*f*, AEI, ACI and NDSI) to a list of 55 60-second wave objects. I have found code which applies the function to a .wav file, however I'm having difficulty in altering the code to work for each component of a list rather than a .wav file.

This is the code im trying to compute:

```
#create function to be applied to list of wave objects
indices <- function(x) {
  x <- readWave(x)
  return(c(sh(meanspec(x, plot=FALSE)),
           acoustic_evenness(x) $aei_left,
           ACI(x),
           NDSI(soundscapespec(x, plot=FALSE))
           )
         )
}

# create data frame for indices to be recorded
n <- length(hodsubsamps0820_000000)
num <- rep (NA, n)
res <- data.frame(Hf=num, AEI=num, ACI=num, NDSI=num)

#use function on each list component
for (i in 1:n) res[i,] <- indices(hodsubsamps0820_000000[i])
```

With this error code:

```
Error in readWave(x) : 'filename' must be of type character.
```

Comment: What does `class(hodsubsamps0820_000000)` return? And `str(hodsubsamps0820_000000)`?

Comment: `> class(hodsubsamps0820_000000)
[1] "list"
> str(hodsubsamps0820_000000)
List of 55
 $ :Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ left     : int [1:2880000] 173 49 -56 -16 -26 97 172 63 208 8 ...
  .. ..@ right    : int [1:2880000] 173 49 -56 -16 -26 97 172 63 208 8 ...
  .. ..@ stereo   : logi TRUE
  .. ..@ samp.rate: int 48000
  .. ..@ bit      : int 16
  .. ..@ pcm      : logi TRUE`
  the results of `str(hodsubsamps0820_000000)` is very long but above is the first component

Comment: `readWave` is expecting a character string and you are passing it a list. The first list member, `hodsubsamps0820_000000[[1]]` is a S4 class object  of class `“Wave”`, so the wave files are already read in. It seems you do *not* need `readWave` in the function.

Comment: as @RuiBarradas points out, your wav files are read in, you're trying to apply the functions found in `soundecology` for the acoustic indices (Hf & etc.) which `soundecology` would do using `multiple_sounds`, [intro_vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/soundecology/vignettes/intro.html), but it anticipates wav files in a directory, so perhaps just point multiple_sounds(directory ='your_directory' , the first index I want), and generate a csv of each index to cbind together into a data.frame.